# Nested for loop doesn't run in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset where all variables are binary (0,1). I want to keep a given value as 1 only if all the other subsequent values in its row are also 1.

To demonstrate, let's say a row looks something like this: 0001111 I would like the 4th object to remain 1. If the row looked something like this: 0100111 I would like the 2nd object to be 0 instead of 1.

I wrote a nested for loop with an if statement, but it doesn't run (Rstudio gets stuck):

```
for (j in 1:(ncol(df)))
{
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)))
 {
if (prod(df[i,j:ncol(df)])==1)
  {
    df[i,j]<-1
  } 
else 
  {
    df[i,j]<-0
   }
  }
 }
```

I also tried running a more general code without a nested for loop, this turns all the values in my dataset to 0s:

```
for (j in 1:(ncol(df)))
 {
if (prod(df[,j:ncol(df)])==1)
  {
    df[,j]<-1
  } 
else 
  {
    df[,j]<-0
   }
  }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I made some sample data: `set.seed(47); df = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, size = 24, replace = TRUE), nrow = 6))` and ran your code - it worked just fine. Can you share some sample data the reproduces the problem? Either share code to simulate sample data as I did here, or share an R object you have with `dput()` so it is copy-pasteable and class/structure information is preserved. For example, `dput(df[1:10, ])` would be great to see, sharing the first 10 rows of your `df` object.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a link to a chunk of the data frame: [link](https://github.com/lbassan/811/blob/master/clean.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally sure why, but once I convert my data frame into a matrix, the code works fine. You can later change it back into a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

Even though I did not look for an error within your code I tried to offer a somewhat more elegant solution:

With the two vectors you provided as example

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1), var2 = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1))
```

we can create a function **consecutive_ones**

```
  consecutive_ones <- function(data) {

  n <- length(data)
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    data[i] <- +(min(data[i:n]) == 1)
  }
  
  return(data)
  
}
```

Whenever all remaining values are 1 (that is, minimum of all remaining values == 1) the value is changed to 1, 0 otherwise.

```
consecutive_ones(data = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1))
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

With the help of the **purrr** package (similar to **lapply**) we can apply this function to a data_frame **columnwise**:

```
purrr::map_df(df, ~consecutive_ones(.x))


   var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0
2     0     0
3     0     0
4     1     0
5     1     1
6     1     1
7     1     1
```

**Note**: Looping through dataframes is not  very efficient, but I guess this is the only feasable approach here.

**Edit:** Even though this is not vectorised and probably inefficient - I provide you a rowwise solution:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[j,] <- consecutive_ones(df[j,])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this. I believe this is set for columns, rather than rows? Either way, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, this way it goes through all rows in each column.  You wanted it to go through all columns for each row?

Comment: yes so in my example 0,0,0,1,1,1,1 and 0,1,0,0,1,1,1 are two rows, with 7 variables/columns, not two columns with 7 rows.

Comment: Thanks again for providing the edit. I tried this on a chunk of my data and it works, but once I ran it on the whole thing it gets stuck like my original code, so I think the problem is perhaps that both your solution and my original one are inefficient and too slow for large datasets..

Comment: Yes indeed my solution (looping through rows) is very ineffective. I will try some more tomorrow

Comment: Sorry I could not find another solution. I will delete my answer